# I am getting error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: jquery

I am trying to delete the record but unfortunately, i am getting the error **caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')** please help me how can I resolve that ?

**jquery**

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
          var deleteId = $(this).data('id');
          var $this = $(this);
          
          swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#4fa7f3',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d57171',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
          }).then(function (result) {
            if (result.value) {
            axios
              .post('{{route("company.destroy")}}', {
                _method: 'delete',
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
                deleteId: deleteId,
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                swal(
                  'Deleted!',
                  'User has been deleted.',
                  'success'
                )

                table.draw();
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                swal(
                  'Failed!',
                  error.response.data.error,
                  'error'
                )
              });
            }
          })
        });
```

Comment: What is `swal`?

Comment: Swal is short for SweetAlert, a popular JavaScript library for creating alert messages with custom styles and functionalities. SweetAlert is designed to replace the default alert, confirm, and prompt dialogs provided by the browser with more visually appealing and interactive modals.